# canActivate does not get called the 2nd time when inner observable emits another value

Tags: angular, observable, angular8, canactivate

I am using `combineLatest`(which combines the values from all the Observables passed as arguments) in the `canActivate` method.

My understanding is that, whenever any one of the observables fires, the canActivate observable needs to fire. But that is not happening

In my AuthorizationGuard, I have the following canActivate method -

```js
public canActivate(route: Route): Observable<boolean> {
    return combineLatest(this.service1.checkRoles(route.routeConfig.data.roles),
                         this.service2.serviceLoadedSub).pipe(
                         map(([isAuthorized, permissions]) => {

        console.log('permission in auth guard');
        console.log(permissionSet);

        // some auth checks
        return isAuthorized;
}
```

service1 checkRoles-

```js
public checkRoles(roles: string[]): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.existingRoles.pipe(
      map(roleMap => {
         // perform some checks

         return true;

      })
    );
  }
```

service 2 -

```js
export class Service2 {
     public serviceLoadedSub: BehaviorSubject<Set<string>> = new BehaviorSubject<Set<string>>(null);

     constructor (private restService: RestService) {
          this.resService.get('url-info').subscribe(data => {

               serviceLoadedSub.next(new Set(data));
          }
      }
}
```

So, when service 2 load completes...the behavior subject is fired again.

But for some reason, the observable in canActiavte does not get fired.

Any idea why?

Comment: So... one of the services fires twice..?

Comment: Why `combineLatest` and not `forkJoin`?